# read multiple file inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the code I have for reading the first item in a file input, how can I iterate over all items inside this input?

```
function readFile (uploadControlId) {
    if (!window.FileReader)
        throw "The browser does not support HTML 5";

    var element = document.getElementById(uploadControlId);

    var def = new $.Deferred();

    var file = element.files[0];
    var parts = element.value.split("\\");
    var fileName = parts[parts.length - 1];

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        if (uploadControlId == 'uploadControlId'){
            def.resolve(e.target.result, fileName);
        } else {
            def.resolve(e.target.result, fileName);
        }

    };
    reader.onerror = function (e) {
        def.reject(e.target.error);
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    return def.promise();
}
```

I have tried something like:

```
angular.forEach(element.files, function (file){
})
```

But this doesn't work since the variables 'parts' and 'fileName' is from the variable 'element', so if I iterate over  each file in element, they get 'undefined' fileName, this means  they won't have like .txt or .pdf, so they are unreadable.

Update: This give no error, but only the last file gets uploaded:

```
    function readFile (uploadControlId) {
    if (!window.FileReader)
        throw "The browser does not support HTML 5";

    var def = new $.Deferred();

    var element = document.getElementById(uploadControlId);

    angular.forEach(element.files, function(file){

        var fileName = file.name;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            def.resolve(e.target.result, fileName);
        };
        reader.onerror = function (e) {
            def.reject(e.target.error);
        };

        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
    return def.promise();
}
```

My upload function:

```
$scope.UploadAttachment = function(){
    readFile(uploadControlId).done(function (buffer, fileName) {

// logic to upload to server

    }).fail(function (err) {
        alert("error in reading file content");
    });

};
```

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; ++i){ }`

Comment: yeah but, how do I set the fileName attribute individually? I need the '.txt' part (or whatever it is the user uploads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the "multiple" attribute on the input tag?

By the way if you add this directive to your tag, an event will be fired with all files and you will handle that in you controller.

```
// Directive
(function(){

    var Directive = function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope : {},
            link : function(scope, element, attrs){
                element.bind('change', function(changeEvent){
                    scope.$emit('fileReader', changeEvent.target.files);
                });
            }
        }
    };

    Directive.$inject = [];

    app.directive('fileReader', Directive);

})();

// Controller
(function(){

    var Controller = function($scope){

        // Methods
        function fileReader(files){

            for(var iFile = 0, fileLen = files.length; iFile < fileLen; iFile = iFile + 1){
                var file = files[iFile];
                // Do something
            }

        }

        // Events
        $scope.$on('fileReader', function(event, files){
            fileReader(files);
        });


    };

    Controller.$inject = [
        '$scope'
    ];

    app.controller('MainCtrl', Controller);

})();
```

Comment: yes I have the 'multiple' tag, it will take me some time to process this answer (I'm new to directives), but I will try it for sure

Comment: I removed the $q dependencies which was useless. You can add "file-reader" as an attribute on your input tag, then after upload you will process the files in the controller.